# Performance comparision of SQL queries versus LINQ in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am new to VS 2012 and need to use it with SQL Server. I need to get data from a table in SQL Server 2012 with 500 rows and 15 columns and process the data in it and update another table. All this has to be done in 100 ms.

I tried traditional method with SQL query filling a dataset and then access the table, rows and item array in each row. It is taking seconds to execute and the time worsening.

Should I use LINQ or another solution?

```
try
{
    connection1.Open();
    adapter_alarms = new SqlDataAdapter(sql_alarms, connection1);
    adapter_alarms.Fill(ds_alarms);
    connection1.Close();
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
}
if (ds_alarms.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ds_alarms.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
            if (bool.Parse(ds_alarms.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[7].ToString()) == true)
                        if (engValues[index] < float.Parse(ds_alarms.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString()))
                        {
                            string sql_Al = "INSERT INTO [MCRCDA].[dbo].[Alarms]([DateTime],[TagName],[AlarmType],[Value],[Units],[Address])    VALUES("+"'10/08/2015'" +", '"+ds_alarms.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString().Trim()+"','Lo',10.4,'C','1.1.1')";
                            try
                            {
                                connection1.Open();
                                adapter_alarms = new SqlDataAdapter(sql_Al, connection1);
                                adapter_alarms.Fill(ds_alarms);
                                connection1.Close();
                            }
                            catch (Exception exp)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
                            }//MessageBox.Show("Lo");
                        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does this code work?  is this the code that you actually run?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the value of  `sql_alarms`

Answer (score 3):

You should factor out some of the dataset selection into a variable, so that you don't have to type that stuff over and over again. This also makes it easier to read.

```
if (ds_alarms.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ds_alarms.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (bool.Parse(ds_alarms.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[7].ToString()) == true)
            if (engValues[index] < float.Parse(ds_alarms.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString()))
            {
                string sql_Al = "INSERT INTO [MCRCDA].[dbo].[Alarms]([DateTime],[TagName],[AlarmType],[Value],[Units],[Address])    VALUES("+"'10/08/2015'" +", '"+ds_alarms.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString().Trim()+"','Lo',10.4,'C','1.1.1')";
                try
                {
                    connection1.Open();
                    adapter_alarms = new SqlDataAdapter(sql_Al, connection1);
                    adapter_alarms.Fill(ds_alarms);
                    connection1.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
                }//MessageBox.Show("Lo");
            }
    }
}
```

Factor out `ds_alarms.Tables[0].Rows` like this:

```
var alarms = ds_alarms.Tables[0].Rows;
if (alarms.Count != 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < alarms.Count; i++)
    {
        if (bool.Parse(alarms[i].ItemArray[7].ToString()) == true)
            if (engValues[index] < float.Parse(alarms[i].ItemArray[3].ToString()))
            {
                string sql_Al = "INSERT INTO [MCRCDA].[dbo].[Alarms]([DateTime],[TagName],[AlarmType],[Value],[Units],[Address])    VALUES("+"'10/08/2015'" +", '"+alarms[i].ItemArray[0].ToString().Trim()+"','Lo',10.4,'C','1.1.1')";
                try
                {
                    connection1.Open();
                    adapter_alarms = new SqlDataAdapter(sql_Al, connection1);
                    adapter_alarms.Fill(ds_alarms);
                    connection1.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**Never** put an if statement inside an if statement without curly braces.  You should extract the two conditionals to variables and then put them in the same if statement like this.

```
var alarms = ds_alarms.Tables[0].Rows;
if (alarms.Count != 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < alarms.Count; i++)
    {
        bool alarm = bool.Parse(alarms[i].ItemArray[7].ToString());
        bool isValue = engValues[index] < float.Parse(alarms[i].ItemArray[3].ToString());

        if (alarm && isValue)
        {
            string sql_Al = "INSERT INTO [MCRCDA].[dbo].[Alarms]([DateTime],[TagName],[AlarmType],[Value],[Units],[Address])    VALUES("+"'10/08/2015'" +", '"+alarms[i].ItemArray[0].ToString().Trim()+"','Lo',10.4,'C','1.1.1')";
            try
            {
                connection1.Open();
                adapter_alarms = new SqlDataAdapter(sql_Al, connection1);
                adapter_alarms.Fill(ds_alarms);
                connection1.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Doesn't that look cleaner? I am sure you can come up with some better variable names than I have for your booleans.

---

You shouldn't hardcode a date into the query string either this will make it very hard to maintain.

In all reality you should create a stored procedure to do that with, and then call that stored procedure with parameters, it's safer and easier to maintain.

---

Now that I look at the code again, it looks very odd. You are pulling data from a dataset in the same loop where you are trying to fill that dataset?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if his entire C# code can be replaced by one single query. But since OP can't be bothered to provide us with that data, who's to know?

Comment: Thanks Mast and Malachi for the suggestions
it really looks cleaner i'll do it like this
actually i need to add a row ion another table on the basis of the data in the dataset (there was a mistake)
 sql_Al.CommandText = same insert query as posted above
sql_Al.ExecuteNonQuery();  called in the innermost if statement

Comment: Dear BCdotWEB i have no objection in sending you the complete code